# Nagios escalations not triggering

Tags: nagios

I'm currently reworking our Nagios configuration to use templates. I defined some host- and services templates like this:

```
define service {
        name                                    8x5servicetemplate
        max_check_attempts                      2
        check_interval                          1
        retry_interval                          1
        check_period                            8x5
        notification_interval                   2
        notification_period                     8x5
        contact_groups                          administrators
        register                                0
}

define service {
        name                                    10x5servicetemplate
        max_check_attempts                      2
        check_interval                          1
        retry_interval                          1
        check_period                            10x5
        notification_interval                   2
        notification_period                     10x5
        contact_groups                          administrators
        register                                0
}

define service {
        name                                    12x5servicetemplate
        max_check_attempts                      2
        check_interval                          1
        retry_interval                          1
        check_period                            12x5
        notification_interval                   2
        notification_period                     12x5
        contact_groups                          administrators
        register                                0
}

define service {
        name                                    24x7servicetemplate
        max_check_attempts                      2
        check_interval                          1
        retry_interval                          1
        check_period                            24x7
        notification_interval                   2
        notification_period                     24x7
        contact_groups                          administrators
        register                                0
}
```

Then I added a simple notification escalation for services:

```
define serviceescalation {
        host_name                               *
        service_description                     *
        first_notification                      3
        notification_interval                   5
        contact_groups                          administrators,developers
}
```

However, I cannot get the escalations to work. Tailing the Nagios log, I can see that only the administrators group gets notified (by XMPP), other users never get any notifications.

I've already tried moving the escalation to the specific host definitions, but that did not change the outcome.

Is there something inherently wrong with my escalation? It's not the configuration cache, other changes instantly show up when reloading the configuration.

Comment: Is it something that you didnt mention developers group in contact groups inside service definition?

Comment: I have trouble understanding what you're asking.

Comment: You haven't mentioned developers group in your service definition. Did you tried developers group mentioning inside your service definition?

Comment: Yes, that is the way I had it before. The developers group was the one getting the notifications before I tried using the escalation. Now, I want to notify developers only as an escalation.

Comment: So, Am I understanding it correctly?

Previously you were not using escalations and you've mentioned developers group directly in your service definition file, resulting in notification for developers group alone.

And now, you want to notify developers for escalations only, and that's why you configured escalations. but currently only administrators are able to get notification. Am I right?

Comment: That's right on the spot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this [document](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/objectdefinitions.html#serviceescalation). It very well says that you need to give last_notification.

But I don't see the same in yours (service escalation definition).

If there is no last_notification or after last_notification time (if you mentioned in general), it will notify your default contact group, which in your case is administrators.

Comment: I need to wait 22 hours before awarding the bounty.

Comment: That's okay. But please dont forget ;) :P